# TYPO3 - Ext cal - PHP Catchable Fatal Error

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I use the Ext "cal", when I add an Image to an Event, i got this Error:

> PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference could not be converted to string
>   in typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/ResourceFactory.php line 430 .

When I disable the Image everything is fine. Any Solutions for that?
TYPO3-Version: 6.2.27

Answer (score 0):

Show your code or the error didn't happen. ;-)

Educated guess: you use a file reference in your view helper instead of using `treatIdAsReference = "1"`